# How can I make a wearable Android app set off the alarm on the handheld?

Tags: android, notifications, wear-os

I created a very simple android wearable app for a watch that uses the accelerometer sensor.  I have the watch connected to a mobile device over bluetooth.  When a certain value is detected by the accelerometer, I'd like for the phone to sound an alarm.  I'm quite new to Android Programming, but I've been trying to read the documentation.  I was looking at the Notification documentation, but I can't seem to figure out which data layer functionality I need.  What I am trying to accomplish seems very simple to me: Run the app on the watch, detect a value, sound alarm on handheld.  The documentation is suggesting a more complicated process.  Am I overthinking this?

Answer (score 1):

Once you detect the event you are interested in on the wear side, you need to send a message to your phone app (using [MessageApi](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/MessageApi)) and then you need to have an implementation of [WearableListenerService](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/WearableListenerService?hl=en) on your phone app that can capture that message and trigger whatever you are interested in.

To send a message to your phone, you should use the [CapabilityApi](http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/messages.html); basically your phone app should declare that it provides, say, "alarm_capability" (or whatever you want to call it) and then your wear, upon detecting the appropriate event, can ask the framework for the connected nodes that provide "alarm_capability". Framework will return the node corresponding to your phone and then you can simply use the [MessageApi](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/MessageApi) to send a message to that node.

All of this is pretty straightforward to do and there are a number of [samples](https://github.com/googlesamples) on our GitHub repo that accomplish similar things (for example, [FindMyPhone](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-FindMyPhone) is pretty close to what you want). You can look a those samples and also read bout the APIs and give it a try. An alternate approach is to use a library that simplifies these steps, for example you can use [WearCompanionLibrary](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-WearCompanionLibrary).

Comment: Excellent!  That greatly helps me to organize the process in my head.  I am going to take a look at the sample and give it try.  Thanks!