# AlarmManager not working in Android wear

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, wear-os

I am trying to invoke AlarmManager from my Android wear project. But for some reasons its failing. Following is my code for the same. I am sure I am calling setAlarm method in AlarmReceiver (my log is printing) but after that nothing happens. My aim is run the alarm every 30 secs. When the AlarmReceiver onReceive is called. SendBroadcast to my Service, which in turn will send the message to server. What am I doing wrong here.

Manifest Details:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

Within Application

```
<receiver android:name=".alarm.AlarmReceiver" />
        <receiver
            android:name=".alarm.SampleBootReceiver"
            android:enabled="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

AlarmManager:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

    private static final String TAG = "AlarmReceiver";

    // The app's AlarmManager, which provides access to the system alarm services.
    private AlarmManager alarmMgr;
    // The pending intent that is triggered when the alarm fires.
    private PendingIntent alarmIntent;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d(TAG,"AlarmReceiver onReceive*******");
        Intent sensorIntent = new Intent("sensor");
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(sensorIntent);
    }

    public void setAlarm(Context context) {
        Log.d(TAG,"Alarm Manager started");
        alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
        alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);

        alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
                System.currentTimeMillis()+1000,60000,alarmIntent);

        ComponentName receiver = new ComponentName(context, SampleBootReceiver.class);
        PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();

        pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(receiver,
                PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
                PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);

    }
}
```

SampleBootReceiver:

```
public class SampleBootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    AlarmReceiver alarm = new AlarmReceiver();
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"))
        {
            alarm.setAlarm(context);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Beginning with API level 19 Alarm delivery is inexact: the OS will shift alarms in order to minimize wakeups and battery use.

This is especially true on wearable devices when in low power mode.

To guarantee delivery use [setExactAndAllowWhileIdle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(int,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent))

> Like `setExact(int, long, PendingIntent)`, but this alarm will be allowed to execute even when the system is in low-power idle modes. If you don't need exact scheduling of the alarm but still need to execute while idle, consider using `setAndAllowWhileIdle(int, long, PendingIntent)`.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check [Creating and Running a Wearable App](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/creating.html) and [Packaging Wearable Apps](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/packaging.html) to ensure you are able to pair your handheld to your wear device.

In wear development, proper communication/pairing between handheld and wearable device is important in sending and receiving messages. Make use of [`MessageApi`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/MessageApi.html), to send message to the wearable to start an activity. To be notified of received messages, implement the [MessageListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/MessageApi.MessageListener.html) interface to provide a listener for message events.

You can also see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38676730/5995040) and another related SO question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34112071/5995040). Also here is a tutorial on [Wearable Notification](https://www.intertech.com/Blog/android-wear-developer-tutorial-wearable-only-notification-with-a-custom-layout/) and [Android Wear Development](https://www.udacity.com/course/android-wear-development--ud875A).

Hope it helps!

Comment: My android wear app and mobile app do not have any issues sending the messages back and forth. I need to time the messages that I send from my watch to phone. For timing, currently I am using Handler.postDelayed which works perfectly fine but I would like to send the message all the time even when the CPU goes to sleep. So I picked this one.